# Passing data from HTTP request to a Sub-component VueJS

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js

i'm running into a bit of an issue with my VueJS **(Vue 2)** application.

I i have a login component, which has a Sub-component called 'error' which is just a bootstrap alert showing a message which should come from the backend (via an HTTP request) the problem is i don't quite know how i can populate this message dynamically after an HTTP request.

So, to reiterate, i have a parent **Login** component which shows a Login form, that component, in it's **Template** requires an **"Error"** sub-component which is just a bootstrap alert.

I need to set a message for that sub-component based on the response from an HTTP request made by the "Login" component, which is the direct parent of the "error" component i want the message to display on...

Do you do this through props? If so how exactly? This is my current HTML template for the **Login** component

```
<template>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Error display component -->
        <error v-if="hasError" v-bind:errorMessage='errorMessage'></error>
        ...Login form HTML....
</template>

<script>
    import Error from './partials/Error.vue';

    export default {
        mounted() {
            this.usernameInput  = document.getElementById('email')
            this.passwordInput  = document.getElementById('password')
            this.submitButton   = document.getElementById('submitBtn')
            this.errorContainer = document.getElementById('errorContainer') 
        },
        methods: {
            submitForm: (e) => {
                e.preventDefault();

            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                usernameInput: undefined,
                passwordInput: undefined,
                submitButton: undefined,
                errorContainer: undefined,
                errorMessage: null,
                hasError: false,
                email: null,
                password: null
            }
        },
        components: {
            'error': Error
        }
    }   
</script>
```

And for the **Error** component

```
<template>
    <div class="alert alert-danger fade in">
    <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
    <strong>Error!</strong> {{ errorMessage }}
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: ['']
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***UPDATE***:

Adapting to your code:

```
methods: {
  submitForm(e) { // dont use fat arrow to not loose context
    e.preventDefault();

    if (some_error) {
      this.hasError = true;
      this.errorMessage = 'Please fix ....';
    }
  }
}
```

And **Error** component:

```
export default {
    props: ['errorMessage']
}
```

---

You would do something like this:

```
Vue.component('login', {
  template: '<div>...</div>',
  data() {
    return { message: '' };
  },
  methods: {
    request() {
      // make a request and then set this.message
    }
  }
})

Vue.component('error', {
  template: '<div>{{ message }}</div>',
  props: ['message']
})
```

Comment: Glad to be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work, much like **Jonatas Walker** said in his post, you should have a `data` variable for the error message on the parent **Login** component, then you should pass it to the child component like this

`<error v-if="hasError" :errorMessage='errorMessage'></error>`

The `:errorMessage='errorMessage'` means i'm v-binding the 'errorMessage' data property into the child as a prop which is also named 'errorMessage'

Then, in my child component's Javascript section i can say

```
    props: ['errorMessage']
```

And then i can use errorMessage in that component as if it were a normal data property defined in that component.

```
{{ errorMessage }}
```

For instance would work fine.